# Does Windows 2008 R2 windows backup requires changes in registry to allow backup of Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, backup

There's a lot of information on web that to enable `Hyper-V` backup in `Windows Backup Tool` you need to do changes in registry before it will allow you to. But are those settings applicable only to `Windows 2008 with Hyper-V` or does `Windows 2008 R2` too requires the changes? Also does `Windows Backup` support snapshots and everything else related to Hyper-V backup?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to use VSS-aware applications, and no it does not support snapshots!